# Returning a typed DataSet from a WCF service result in a 'xs:string' not found

Tags: c#, xml, wcf

Considering a server that expose a service through WCF. One of the `OperationContract` return a typed DataSet called `TraceDataSet` that contains a snapshot of the trace on the server.

When the dataset is returned, the `ReadXml` that is occurring inside the custom visual studio tool generated file, in the method `ReadXmlSerializable` throws a

> Undefined data type: 'xs:string'.

I added WCF trace on the client and server, but the WCF communication works perfectly.

I did some research, but nothing is conclusive and I also get 404 errors from the MSDN forums.

I checked the stream behind the XmlReader and it does contains the declaration of the `xmlns:xs` namespace, so I'm a bit confused there.

If I serialize the DataSet to a file on the server (which run locally for debugging purpose) and I read that file from the client, it does work, so I'm suspecting that something is occurring through the WCF communication even if it does not fail.

The typed DataSet is declared in a shared assembly that is reference by both the client and the server. We are not using a regenerated DataSet created by a proxy in the /References folder.

We never had any problem concerning the trace, until recently, and sadly, we can't point to the change that caused this feature to break.

Does anybody have an idea why `ReadXml` can't find the `xs:string` data type?

Comment: +1 for trying a bunch of things and telling us what they are.

Comment: Did you happen to see this thread? http://forums.asp.net/p/1265752/2382525.aspx  It specifically mentions typed DataSets.

Comment: Interesting link, we use a DataSet in a shared assembly, so the /References folder does not contains a reconstructed version of the DataSet, so this may not apply, but I'll look it up.

Comment: Is the `xs` prefix defined? Is the schema for which it's defined specified in a `schemaLocation` attribute?

Comment: I remembered having this error with the TraceDataSet, check in the svn log to see if I did something to fixed it :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I search in forums and other site, i found that it seems this is a bug in the serialization in some circonstance in System.Data. I dont know how to fix this bug, but i found a work arround :

Put the Dataset in a string ( with getXml() on the traceData), and send it to the client. The client received the string and rebuild the dataset. This is not a fix, but it a workaround and it work for me.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this same error when using a SQL statement that did not result in a specific data type, such as:

```
SELECT SERVERPROPERTY('ComputerNamePhysicalNetBIOS') AS CurrentMachineName
```

I changed by SQL query to instead specify the data type I wanted, such as:

```
SELECT CAST(SERVERPROPERTY('ComputerNamePhysicalNetBIOS') AS varchar(255)) AS CurrentMachineName
```

and that corrected the problem.  Now the dataset was given the specific data type and not a generic "anytype" which was translated in XML as xs:string.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. The problem was, that some of the tables in DataSet had column's property **DataType** set to type Object. That type is not serializable.

Check **DataType** property's value if it is serializable, in all columns in all tables. If not, change it to a serializable type or remove those columns. That should fix the problem.

Answer (score -1):

I could be wrong, but I don't think WCF supports DataSets.  Whenever I use WCF I only use POCO classes.  I'm thinking you want to copy the data to a Trace class, then return an array of Trace objects.

Comment: I can tell you for sure that it does work, we've been using that serialization for the past years to solve problem on our installation, by reading the server log. I guess a deeper analysis of the commits by the team would help us pinpoint the problem. We already did that, but maybe we overlooked something.

Comment: Not true - the DataContractSerializer can handle DataSets in general: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa347876.aspx